# How to identify similar records in a List and then updating corresponding fields

Tags: soql, list, roll-up-summary, after-trigger, group-by-rollup

```
trigger setCertificationToFailed on Exam__c (after update) {
     List<Exam__c> ExamList = new List<Exam__c>();
     ExamList = [SELECT Id, Exam_id__c, Exam_state__c, doNothingExam__c, Certification__r.Id, Certification__r.Exam_state__c, Certification__r.Name FROM Exam__c 
                 WHERE Exam_state__c in ('Failed') AND Certification__r.Exam_state__c in ('Active') AND doNothingExam__c = True];
}
```

I need to identify if each row inside this List share similar values with other rows of the same list.

eg. **Row 1** => Certification__r.Id = ABCD, Exam_id__c = 1234,
**Row 2** => Certification.Id = EFGH, Exam_id__c = 0000,
**Row 3** => Certification.Id = ABCD, Exam_id__c = 1234

Above Row 1 and 3 have same Certification__r.Id, Exam_id__c. How can I identify this through a code?.

Note that only Certification__r.Id, Exam_id__c should be compared with every row. If both of them match together with another row, then it should change Certification__r.Exam_state__c to 'FAILED' from 'Active'

Below in this picture, you can notice similar rows with similar Certification__r.Id, Exam_id__c values.

[image: Query run on Developer Console]

Comment: Please, explain, if **Row 1** => Certification__r.Id = ABCD, Exam_id__c = **1234** and **Row 2** => Certification__r.Id = ABCD, Exam_id__c = **5678**
Would they count as same for you? Or should they have in common both certification id and exam id?

Comment: hi @MariiaIllarionova they should have only Certification__r.Id, Exam_id__c in common. then depending on that, i should update field Certification__r.Exam_state__c to 'failed' from active. Please see my updated image

Comment: when both Certification__r.Id, Exam_id__c are equal, it will count as same @MariiaIllarionova
it doesn't count when either one of it is different. hope i answered your question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
List<Exam__c> exams = new List<Exam__c>();
exams = [
        SELECT Id, Exam_id__c, Exam_state__c, doNothingExam__c, Certification__r.Id, Certification__r.Exam_state__c, Certification__r.Name 
        FROM Exam__c];

//here we are formatting the map to identify duplicates
Map<String, List<Exam__c>> toCheck = new Map<String, List<Exam__c>>();
Set<Id> certificationIds = new Set<Id>();

for (Exam__c exam_i : exams) {
    certificationIds.add(exam_i.Certification__r.Id);
    String validationString = exam_i.Exam_id__c + exam_i.Certification__r.Id;
    if (!toCheck.containsKey(validationString)) {
        toCheck.put(validationString, new List<Exam_c>());
    }

    toCheck.put(validationString, toCheck.get(validationString).add(exam_i));
}

Map<Id, Certification__c> certificationMap = new Map<Id, Certification__c>([SELECT Id, Exam_state__c FROM Certification__c WHERE Id IN :certificationIds]);

//here we are updating statuses
for (List<Exam__c> examList_i : toCheck.values()) {
    if (examList_i.size() > 1) {
        for (Integer i = 1; i < examList_i.size() ; i++) {
            Certification__c tmp = certificationMap.get(examList_i[i].Certification__r.Id);
            tmp.Exam_state__c = 'FAILED';
            certificationMap.put(examList_i[i].Certification__r.Id, tmp);
        }
    }
}

update certificationMap.values();
```

**Explanation**:
If both certification id and exam id are important to you, then combine them and save as map keys.
Also you need to update Certification__c later in the code as I have written.

Comment: how will the code change if i add both the certification id and exam_id__c(string). Also certification id is an id, and exam_id__c is a string. please help

Comment: Id easely converts to string when concatenating: ```String validationString = exam_i.Exam_id__c + exam_i.Certification__r.Id;``` If you're not sure, you can type: ```String validationString = String.valueOf(exam_i.Exam_id__c) + exam_i.Certification__r.Id;```

Then, how it will help you: 1234ABSD is the same with 1234ABCD from your example (Row 1 and Row 3), so the map will have 2 keys: 1234ABCD and 000EFGH, and the first key will correspond list with 2 exams.

Comment: You'll get all the values in the list except the first one ,and change corresponding certification states to failed, because the are duplicates.

Comment: toCheck.put(validationString, new List<Exam__c>()); what does the new List do here?  ... toCheck.put(validationString, toCheck.get(validationString).add(exam_i)); - this line shows an error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(String, Object) from the type Map<String,List<Exam__c>>"

Comment: I just initialize it there if the map doesn'y contain validation string yet. It prevents getting null-pointer exception with toCheck.get(validationString)

Comment: Write it like this:
```List<Exam__c> tmp = toCheck.get(validationString); tmp.add(exam_i); toCheck.put(validationString, tmp);```

Comment: the above code sets certification__r.Exam_state__c to 'FAILED' when it fails one exam.
but to fix that, i added WHERE Exam_state__c in ('Failed') AND Certification__r.Exam_state__c in ('Active') AND doNothingExam__c = True]; to the query. and it seems to work. But is this correct? can you verify

Comment: It is not necessary in my opinion, because you check it later in the code.

Comment: But when you do it without that part, the exam is set to 'failed' without even having a duplicate. But it should be set to 'failed' only when it encounters a duplicate, it's not happening without that part. Can you have a look please?

Comment: With all my attitude I haven't gone through your code so far. My code is just an example how to get to the exact solution, any modifications you do are acceptable and wanted. Suit this code in any need.